# D3 Bar chart. Values not aligned with Y axis

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bar-chart

I am facing an issue while plotting values. The bars go beyond Y-Axis.

```
<div id = "Bar1">
        <script>

        var margin1 = {top: 40, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
            width1 = 460 //- margin.left - margin.right,
            height1 = 200 //- margin.top - margin.bottom;

        var formatPercent1 = d3.format("");

        var x1 = d3.scale.ordinal()
            .rangeRoundBands([0, width1], 0);
            //.rangeRoundBands([width1, 0);

        var y1 = d3.scale.linear()
            .range([height1, 0]);

        var xAxis1 = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(x1)
            .orient("bottom");

        var yAxis1 = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(y1)
            .orient("left")
            .tickFormat(formatPercent1);

        var tip1 = d3.tip()
          .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
          .offset([-10, 0])
          .html(function(d) {
            return "<strong>Frequency:</strong> <span style='color:red'>" + d.frequency + "</span>";
          })

        var svg1 = d3.select("#Bar1").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width1 + margin1.left + margin1.right)
            .attr("height", height1 + margin1.top + margin1.bottom)
          .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin1.left + "," + margin1.top + ")");

        svg1.call(tip1);

        d3.tsv(data, type, function(error, data1) {
          x1.domain(data1.map(function(d) { return d.letter; }));
          y1.domain([0, d3.max(data1, function(d) { return d.frequency; })]);

          svg1.append("g")
              .attr("class", "x axis")
              .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height1 + ")")
              .call(xAxis1);

          svg1.append("g")
              .attr("class", "y axis")
              .call(yAxis1)
            .append("text")
              .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
              .attr("y", 6)
              .attr("dy", ".71em")
              .style("text-anchor", "end")
              .text("Frequency");

          svg1.selectAll(".bar")
              .data(data1)
            .enter().append("rect")
              .attr("class", "bar")
              .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.letter); })
              .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
              .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.frequency); })
              .attr("height", function(d) { return height1 - y(d.frequency); })
              .on('mouseover', tip1.show)
              .on('mouseout', tip1.hide)

        });

        function type(d) {
          d.frequency = +d.frequency;
          return d;
        }

        </script>
    </div>

The CSV:
letter  frequency
django  12
dictionary  33
C   55
D   100
E   90
F   300
G   80
H   10
I   0
J   0
```

[image]
Can Anyone please help me out with this code. I am not understanding why this is an issue.
The X and Y axis are scaled too. Is there something that i have missed out?

Thanks,
Sriram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have a mistake elsewhere than in the code you sent. I just put it to JSFiddle and it works correctly:

```js
var tsv = "letter frequency\n" + 
    "django 12\n" + 
    "dictionary 33\n" + 
    "C 55\n" + 
    "D 100\n" + 
    "E 90\n" + 
    "F 300\n" + 
    "G 80\n" + 
    "H 10\n" + 
    "I 0\n" + 
    "J 0";

var margin1 = {top: 40, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width1 = 460 //- margin.left - margin.right,
    height1 = 200 //- margin.top - margin.bottom;

var formatPercent1 = d3.format("");

var x1 = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width1], 0);
    //.rangeRoundBands([width1, 0);

var y1 = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height1, 0]);

var xAxis1 = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x1)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis1 = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y1)
    .orient("left")
    .tickFormat(formatPercent1);


var svg1 = d3.select("#Bar1").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width1 + margin1.left + margin1.right)
    .attr("height", height1 + margin1.top + margin1.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin1.left + "," + margin1.top + ")");

var data1 = d3.tsv.parse(tsv, type)
x1.domain(data1.map(function(d) { return d.letter; }));
y1.domain([0, d3.max(data1, function(d) { return d.frequency; })]);

svg1.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height1 + ")")
  .call(xAxis1);

svg1.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis1)
.append("text")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
  .attr("y", 6)
  .attr("dy", ".71em")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .text("Frequency");

svg1.selectAll(".bar")
  .data(data1)
.enter().append("rect")
  .attr("class", "bar")
  .attr("x", function(d) { return x1(d.letter); })
  .attr("width", x1.rangeBand())
  .attr("y", function(d) { return y1(d.frequency); })
  .attr("height", function(d) { return height1 - y1(d.frequency); })

function type(d) {
  d.frequency = +d.frequency;
  return d;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id='Bar1'></div>
```

In your snippet, you are referring to x scale as `x` variable, while you actually save it in `x1`. The same goes for `y` and `y1` variables. That's corrected in my snippet.

Other than that, I changed the TSV loading from `d3.tsv` to `d3.tsv.parse`, but that's just skipping the AJAX fetch of the resource. I also removed the `d3.tip` tooltip, but again, that shouldn't change the barchart itself.

From the looks of your image, I'd guess you're not converting the `frequency` to `Number` but leave it as a `String`. But that's just a guess, you might want to show the actual code that's giving you trouble.

Comment: Hi Veprosa, Thanks for the reply. I copy pasted your code and it does seem to work. Can you let me know what changes u did. Apart from getting the CSV contents into the variable "tsv". Also there was a gap earlier between the rectangles.Can you please let me know if you made change to that piece.

Comment: Hi, I edited in the changes, but you summed it up - I changed to `d3.tsv.parse` inline parsing, I also fixed the `x` and `x1` confusion and removed `d3.tip` for clarity. As for the gaps, I didn't touch that part of the code. If you want gaps, you might want to change `.attr("width", x1.rangeBand())` to something like `.attr("width", x1.rangeBand() - 1)` or whathever gap size you wish to have.