# d3 svg bar chart values exceeding y axis

Tags: d3.js, svg, bar-chart

I am looking at an example on d3 svg bar chart (Example taken from [Bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29715082/d3-bar-chart-values-not-aligned-with-y-axis) by modifying data)

```
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id='Bar1'></div>

 var tsv = "letter  frequency\n" + 
    "django 12\n" + 
    "dictionary 33\n" + 
    "C  55\n" + 
    "D  100\n" + 
    "E  90\n" + 
    "F  320\n" + 
    "G  80\n" + 
    "H  10\n" + 
    "I  0\n" + 
    "J  0";

var margin1 = {top: 40, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width1 = 460 //- margin.left - margin.right,
    height1 = 200 //- margin.top - margin.bottom;

var formatPercent1 = d3.format("");

var x1 = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width1], 0);
    //.rangeRoundBands([width1, 0);

var y1 = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height1, 0]);

var xAxis1 = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x1)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis1 = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y1)
    .orient("left")
    .tickFormat(formatPercent1);


var svg1 = d3.select("#Bar1").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width1 + margin1.left + margin1.right)
    .attr("height", height1 + margin1.top + margin1.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin1.left + "," + margin1.top + ")");

var data1 = d3.tsv.parse(tsv, type)
x1.domain(data1.map(function(d) { return d.letter; }));
y1.domain([0, d3.max(data1, function(d) { return d.frequency; })]);

svg1.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height1 + ")")
  .call(xAxis1);

svg1.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis1)
.append("text")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
  .attr("y", 6)
  .attr("dy", ".71em")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .text("Frequency");

svg1.selectAll(".bar")
  .data(data1)
.enter().append("rect")
  .attr("class", "bar")
  .attr("x", function(d) { return x1(d.letter); })
  .attr("width", x1.rangeBand())
  .attr("y", function(d) { return y1(d.frequency); })
  .attr("height", function(d) { return height1 - y1(d.frequency); })

function type(d) {
  d.frequency = +d.frequency;
  return d;
}
```

and the output of above code is as in the below image.

[image]

If we observe the bar represented by "F  320\n", its exceeding the y-axis value (where max value on y-axis is 300).

Can someone let me know if there is a possibility to show 320 on y axis so that bar represented by "F" will be shown without exceeding the Y-axis max value?

Comment: Add `.nice()` to the scale?

Comment: *"... where max value on y-axis is 300"*. That's not correct. `300` is the last number in the axis. The max value is the last tick, which is just above `300`. The bar is not exceeding the y axis. If you want to create a padding just change the last value in the domain.

Comment: yes yes. The last value on y axis is 300. Is there a way to set the last value on y-axis based on the Max value in data?

Comment: @RyanMorton, Let me check if .nice() works

Comment: @RyanMorton, nice() is rounding off the max value displayed. Its good. But is there a way where i can set max value as the last value on y-axis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a specific tick to your axis at the max value

```
// Get ticks
var ticks = y1.ticks();

// Add a tick at y max
ticks.push(d3.max(data1, function(d) { return d.frequency; }));

// Add all ticks to the y axis
var yAxis1 = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y1)
    .orient("left")
    .tickFormat(formatPercent1)
    .tickValues(ticks);
```

Or you can manually set all ticks:

```
// Add custom ticks to the y axis
var yAxis1 = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y1)
    .orient("left")
    .tickFormat(formatPercent1)
    .tickValues([80, 160, 240, 320]);
```

Comment: Thanks @roland. I didn't knew we have a method ticks. I was able to use it to achieve the functionality.